# Ubuntu 13 and Windows 7 are not friends

Tags: installation, 13.04, dual-boot

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 64. I wanted to install it to dual boot with windows 7 64 bit.
The computer is a HP dv6 with Intel i7; 8 GB of RAM, and a 1 TB HDD.

I tried for days to install Ubuntu but after reading a great deal on this site, I found out HP tools and Windows took up all 4 portions on the HDD. So I wiped out all the HP tools and restore stuff.

I then installed Ubuntu. It wiped out Windows and my computer couldn't even see the hard drive. So I put the HDD in my other computer and was able to save all my data. I did a low level format and then reinstalled Windows, making sure not to let the HP tools back on the drive. This left me with Windows 7 only in my HDD.

Then I tried to install Ubuntu a second time. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/2/) to the nail.  It all seemed to go well: I created `/boot`, `/` and `/home` partitions; I didn't create a swap since I have 8 GB of RAM. It finished installing and said I needed to reboot. After I reboot, Windows loads up but no way to access Ubuntu.

I've never used it and I am at a lost, it's so different from Windows. :(

Fixing Windows based systems is what I do, so I'm always the one giving help. I would be so very grateful for any help.

Comment: I have the exact same situation (downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 64. I wanted to install it to dual boot with windows 7 64 bit) and I had the Hp tools and recovery taking up all 4 portions problem. However, I only removed HP recovery. Maybe (just maybe!) removing HP tools caused your problem. I'm just speculating.

Comment: Here's how I did it: I removed HP recovery partition by going to Start Menu(search)->HP Recovery Manager->Remove Recovery Partition. Then, I just restarted my computer onto my USB flash drive (which has the Ubuntu booter thing), and I had the option to install Ubuntu *alongside* my other operating system(windows 7). But I'm having [problems](http://askubuntu.com/questions/320489/ubuntu-wont-boot-after-successful-installation) too

Comment: I removed em both with out error and will never put em back as I just don't need it. But I will try that option see what happens. I'll keep at it tell I get it the way I want it

Answer (score 2):

The guide you were using suggests to install the grub bootloader to "Sda5", meaning the bootloader is installed to a partition rather than a drive (making it impossible to boot without additional software because your computer cannot look for bootloaders on a partition), after installing Ubuntu the guide further instructs you to add an additional ubuntu grub boot entry, this time to the windows bootloader using EasyBCD from windows. I'm guessing you didn't do that part of the guide yet? Which is why you cannot boot ubuntu yet. You can download easybcd and use it to add your ubuntu boot entry (instructions are in the guide you were using), or you can re-install ubuntu and set the bootloader to install to sda rather than sda5. The reason the guide is instructing you to install to sda5 is so that you can avoid erasing the windows bootloader, making things easier if you decide to ditch ubuntu down the road.

sincerely, tapthoseshoesandwish

Comment: Well yea I guess I missed that part. It's all working now. Thank you guys so much. I ended up reformatting The drive and leaving 167 gigs unformatted. wiping out recovery and HP tools for good then used the install along side windows option. It worked perfect. I hope to stick with Ubuntu. As I just am so sick of windows. They are just like the government making it harder and harder for you use anything all in the name of keeping me safe! Sure wish everyone would stop trying to save me! Anyway sorry moving on. You can close this or mare it solved Thank you all again meant a lot to me

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit difficult to understand, but it sounds like you've somehow managed to not install Ubuntus boot loader to your primary disk. This is necessary for any operating system. I'm not entirely sure why you performed manual partitioning as Ubuntus installer is very good at this and obviously makes it a lot easier. Disabling swap is also not necessarily a very good idea, as it's used if you ever want to hibernate, for instance.

You made things a lot easier when you freed up partitions. But I recommend that you delete those manually created partitions and just select "use free space" in Ubuntus installer.

Comment: I didn't know any other way to do it. I just fallowed the steps of the tut I posted a link to. I know windows inside and out. But this is my 1st time even looking at any OS other then windows. It may sound crazy but with out knowing anything I goggled a tut and followed it to the nail. All I want is to install them on the same drive and pick on at boot I can do this easy with say windows xp and windows 7 but I just don't get Ubuntu. But the 1st time it wiped out everything so that why I look for a tut... I see no option to use free space only options is install over windows install with

Answer (score 1):

I have a new hp all in one with win. 7   I went into bios and disabled secure boot and enabled legacy boot. Everything work fine with no problems. The first time I tried I just enabled legacy boot and it did not install grub.

The key is you have to disable secure boot **first**, then enable legacy boot.

Answer (score 0):

You have a limit of 4 primary partitions, and your win7 computer uses all of them, just like mine was.

I did the following :-

- Boot into the live cd
- start the partition manager.
- Kept the media partition for the linux partition
- Resized the other partitions so that the partition was as large as I wanted to.
- (Reboot to make sure I can still start Win7)
- Boot into the live cd and start the installer
- Install into the partition I set aside (the partitions I created for my Ubuntu install were logical partition