# Failed to install ubuntu 13.10 and it also corrupted my windows 7

Tags: installation, partitioning

i tried to install ubuntu 13.10 from bootable usb but it failed and it also corrupt my windows 7. 
then again i tried to install ubuntu it shows that i have no operating system currently. i select the first option for installation that erase data and install(something like that) i do it but after completion of installation it again shows the option to install ubuntu or use without installation.
so, i want to ask that first thing that my all partition that i have created in window 7 will remains in exist or not?
and how to solve this problem?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/320469/ubuntu-13-and-windows-7-are-not-friends/343003#343003  check this question out. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

After the installation process is complete, you should reboot / restart the computer without the live usb installation media removed, and Ubuntu will boot from hard drive.

If you selected the option to erase all data and install, and the installation process was successful, then your partitions were most likely delete.